# salesforce1 embedded visualforcepage hyperlink opening the same page again

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

VF page page1 is embedded inside account detail page. page1 has link1 ( tag) that has the following JS-

```
javascript:sforce.one.navigateToURL(urlToOpen,true);
```

to open the link .

on mobile (android), when I click on link1(inside iframe) , it opens page1  again in another window and now when I click on link1 second time, takes me to the url. Is there any workaround to open the link with one click? this works on desktop browser.

Comment: Can you share your complete code snippet?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/394823225e504368c551